# Pandas - unify dataframe horizontally turning the rows into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames which I want to combine in a horizontal way. I'll explain myself:

DataFrame A:

```
  Name      Total Score
 Charles         67
 Peter           98
 Mark            78
```

DataFrame B:

```
Name        Category        Score
Charles    Category A         4
Charles    Category B         9
Peter      Category A         3
Peter      Category B         1
Mark       Category A         3
Mark       Category B         3
```

what I want to do is generate a new data frame that consolidates this information horizontally:

```
  Name    Category A     Category B     Total Score
Charles        4             9               67   
Peter          3             1               98
Mark           3             3               78
```

I clarify that my dataframe has dozens of categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`merge` df on the `pivot`ted df2:

```
df.merge(df2.pivot('Name', 'Category', 'Score'), left_on='Name', right_index=True)

      Name  Total Score  Category A  Category B
0  Charles           67           4           9
1    Peter           98           3           1
2     Mark           78           3           3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I try this solution in my data I get "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"